# D3 tooltip position offset from mouse when hosted on sharepoint

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, sharepoint

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="chart1">
    <div class="tooltip"></div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS for the tooltip

```
.tooltip
{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px;

    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

and here is my JS

```
pie.on("mouseenter",function(){
    d3.select("#chart1 .tooltip").style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on('mousemove',function(d){
    var tooltip = d3.select("#chart1 .tooltip");
    show_data(tooltip,d);  // custom function to populate tooltip html

    tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 50) + "px")     
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 40) + "px");
});
```

This works perfectly on my local machine, both in Chrome and Explorer Edge.
But when I host all of the files on sharepoint, the tooltip is offset from the mouse pointer. It still follows the same direction as the mouse, but there is a gap in the Y position.

Please see the image below to understand what is going on.
[image: mouse position gap with tooltip]

I tried a combination of things, including using `window.pageYOffset` but that did not work. I am sure sharepoint is adding `iframes` or sub-html documents behind the scene which makes the mouse position on the SVG element differs from when the file is directly displayed without sharepoint intervention.

What can I do to make the tooltip stick to the mouse position on sharepoint hosted files?

Comment: Have you tried using `d3.mouse` instead of using `d3.event.pageX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my question.

Instead of populating  pure html element with tooltip data, I decided to create an SVG group within my chart.

That worked perfectly across all browsers and even locally

```
var pie = svg.selectAll(".pie")
   .on('mouseenter',show_tooltip)
   .on('mousemove',move_tooltip)
   .on('mouseout',hide_tooltip );


function create_tooltip() {
    tooltip = svg.append("g")
                 .attr("class","tooltip");

    tooltip.append("rect").attr("class","box");
    tooltip.append("text").attr("id","division");

    tooltip.append("rect").attr("id","legend")
                          .attr("width","20")
                          .attr("height","20");

}

function move_tooltip(d) {
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    var x = coords[0] - 30;
    var y = coords[1] - 40;
    tooltip.attr("transform","translate("+x+","+y+")");
}


function hide_tooltip(d) {
    tooltip.transition().attr("opacity","0");
}

function show_tooltip(d) {
    tooltip.transition().delay(500).attr("opacity","0.95");
    tooltip.select("#division").text(d.data.division);
    tooltip.select("#legend").attr("fill",function(){ 
        return color(d.data.division) 
    });
}
```